# Using an alternative SSL library in JBoss; move ramifications

Tags: ssl, jboss

I'd like to use an alternative SSL library like `GnuTLS` on JBOSS for secure connection. Am I right that GnuTLS can't be used on JBOSS since it's written in C? Apart from that, does JBOSS only support `OpenSSL` and `JSSE` (keytool) libraries?

The reason I'm considering the move is for security reasons. Will this make any real change since all SSL libraries use the same algorithms like RSA?
So, if I keep using OpenSSL or keytool, will the application stay equally secure?

Comment: AFAIK all SSL libraries do use the same algorithms where standards dictate that, but do have differences where they don't. E.g. in where they take source data for key generation.